# How to restore Monero RPC Wallet from seed

Tags: mnemonic-seed, monero-wallet-rpc, rpc

I would like to use the seed to restore wallet from RPC. However, I couldn't find it in this RPC command list below.

https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#create_wallet

If it is not possible, would there be any other practical way to do this task?

Comment: how is restoring from RPC distinct from just restoring from seed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A command has been [added](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/commit/f3019efe1b04cbb835927c4ec349d57d5991fa17) to restore from a seed, the documentation is just a little outdated.

The parameters are:

```
  uint64_t restore_height;
  std::string filename;
  std::string seed;
  std::string seed_offset;
  std::string password;
  std::string language;
```

Which should all be self-explanatory.